RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 using contact.phones!.elementAt(0).value
I am developing an application where I should access the contacts of the user. I am using contacts_service and permission_handler to access the contacts and here is my code:
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  List<Contact> contacts = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllContacts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: contacts.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                Contact contact = contacts[i];
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(contact.displayName!),
                  subtitle: Text(contact.phones!.elementAt(0).value.toString()),
                );
          }));
  }

  void getAllContacts() async {
    List<Contact> _contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false);
    setState(() {
      contacts = _contacts;
    });
  }
}

and I added the lines below to my AndroidManifest.xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

Problem
I get a range error:
The following RangeError was thrown building:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

If I comment the subtitle part everything is fine. so the problem is that contact_service can not get the contact phone numbers and I don't know why.
anyone can help me?
I tried flutter_contacts  and I have the same issue with the getContacts function but getContact  works fine

so at first I switched to flutter_contacts because the getContact for having a specific contact object worked, Although this is a hard way. But I figured that I had to use the withProperties: true option. I could not find the same option in contact_service. Everything works with flutter_contacts.
first of all don't forget to use the below command on the project directory:
flutter pub add flutter_contacts

then use this code:
if (!await FlutterContacts.requestPermission(
   readonly: true)) {
   // Handle permission denied state
  } else {
      contacts = await FlutterContacts.getContacts(withProperties: true);
      // Handle permission granted and update contacts
  }


Replace the getAllContacts function with
  void getAllContacts() async {
    if(await FlutterContacts.requestPermission()) {
      List<Contact> _contacts = await FlutterContacts.getContacts(withProperties: true);
      setState(() {
        contacts = _contacts;
      });
    }
  }
}

subtitle with
subtitle: Text(contact.phones.isNotEmpty ? contact.phones.first.number : '(none)'),

and replace the import statement from
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';

to
import 'package:flutter_contacts/flutter_contacts.dart';

it should work fine with flutter_contacts.

So, it can be summarised "use flutter_contacts rather than contact_service and contact.phones will not be empty"?

Unfortunately no, the getContacts does not work in flutter_contacts too, but there is a getContact method that gets the contact's id and return the specific contact. this way I can use the contact phones. this function does not exist in contact_service.

I mentioned all of these in the question. also if you want to change the package to flutter_contacts you have to change it in pubspec.yaml to and run flutter pub get which you did not mention in your answer.
